# Удаление нескольких сообщений бота Telegram. Как реализовать?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Мой бот сделан на python-telegram-bot и отправляет по два сообщения при помощи InlineKeyboardButton, новое меню - новая функция, и мне хотелось бы очищать все предыдущие сообщения, но данные update.callback_query сохраняют только последнее из них. Как я могу узнать id предпоследнего сообщения в одной функции, перенести его в другую и использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Методы send_message, send_photo, edit_message_text и т.д. возвращают объект типа Message, у которого есть поле message_id и поле chat.id которые необходимы для метода delete_message. Можно их записывать в базу данных в первой функции, сразу после отправки. После чего в нужный момент мы получаем из базы все message_id и chat.id и удаляем все сообщения с указанными значениями.

Вот фрагмент моего кода. В нём две функции, одна для записи данных в базу в таблицу, индивидуальную для каждого пользователя, вторая для удаления всех записанных сообщений, отправленных данному пользователю.

```
import connect


def record_id(message_id, chat_id, first_name):

con = connect.create_connect()

con.set_isolation_level(connect.psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages_for_delete_"+first_name+" (message_id integer, chat_id integer)")

cur.execute("INSERT INTO messages_for_delete_"+first_name+" (message_id, chat_id) VALUES ("+str(message_id)+","+str(chat_id)+")")

con.close()

cur.close()


def delete_recorded(first_name, bot):

con = connect.create_connect()

con.set_isolation_level(connect.psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM messages_for_delete_"+str(first_name)+"")

messages_for_delete = cur.fetchall()

for message in messages_for_delete:

    bot.delete_message(
        chat_id=message[1],
        message_id=message[0])


cur.execute("DROP TABLE messages_for_delete_"+str(first_name))

con.close()

cur.close()
```